# Storing shared values in SQLite database vs passing through intents

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-intent

My app initially makes a request for a list of objects from a server. These objects are currently kept in memory as an `ArrayList<MyObject>`. However, I want these objects to be passed through multiple activities before the user terminates the flow by pressing a button. I *could* make the ArrayList serializable and pass it through Intent extras. But I could also store `MyObject`(s) in a SQLite database and access/modify them in any Activity without having to go though intents. I was wondering what the norm is to accomplish this.

EDIT: forgot to mention that all the values would be deleted once the user terminates the flow.

Comment: Do you need the whole arraylist to be passed between activities? Or are you only passing one object at a time? For example, if one activity displays the whole list and another displays the details of one clicked item, you don't really need to pass the whole arraylist

Comment: Yes, I have a special use case for doing so. I'm displaying some data in a different way in a different activity.

Comment: Perhaps you can contain the entire flow in one Activity with multiple Fragments instead. Then each Fragment can acquire the values by calling its host Activity.

Comment: @Karakuri that's an interesting thought, however the current Activity which contains the list data is already made up of two large-ish fragments. I don't want to compromise the readability of my app for future maintenance

Comment: It's also possible breaking it up into smaller fragments might actually improve readability, but I can't make that judgment without knowing anything about your code base.

Comment: @Karakuri yes, thank you for your suggestion. I will try to make that judgement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is not the best way to go in your case since you don't need the data to be persistent after you close the app. It will just slow your app having to store and retrieve all entries on every activity transition. You can do one of the following instead:

1. Pass `Serializable` the way you described. Might be slower than the other alternatives though
2. Make `MyObject` implement [`Parcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and use [`intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList))
3. Extend [`Application`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and load the list from the network in your `Application.onCreate()` and call `getList()` from activities that need it. That way you load it once and you don't need to pass it between different activities.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into Parcelable. Any foreseeable downsides with it?

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, it's very straightforward. Just make sure to include all your object fields in both `MyObject(Parcel in)` and `writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)` methods.

Comment: I actually just implemented this and it's working great, thanks!